# Delphi 10.2.1 iOS Ad-hoc Create Error?

Tags: ios, delphi

i developed an iOS app via Delphi 10.2 tokyo + XCode 8.2 and MacOS Sierra. i update Delphi Tokyo 10.2.1 and XCode 8.3.3. i update paserver also with new version. Before i create ad-hoc ipa easily but now Delphi won't create ad-hoc ipa. it gives error:

```
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 2017-08-11 14:39:54.883 xcodebuild[882:112306] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/8s/dd6gm22x3vgg0z2szlygpqgr0000gn/T/MyProgram_2017-08-11_14-39-54.882.xcdistributionlogs'.
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 error: exportArchive: exportOptionsPlist error for key 'method': expected one of {app-store, developer-id, development}, but found ad-hoc
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "exportOptionsPlist error for key 'method': expected one of {app-store, developer-id, development}, but found ad-hoc" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=exportOptionsPlist error for key 'method': expected one of {app-store, developer-id, development}, but found ad-hoc}
[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 ** EXPORT FAILED **
```

i try to find a solutions but couldn't found. How can i solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. Embarcadero release a fix for this :

http://cc.embarcadero.com/Download.aspx?id=30797

i doesn't try yet.